# Can't find image exported from AIR app on Android phone

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I feel as if I'm missing something very basic here. I'm trying to add an option to let export images from an Android app in PNG format. The code seems to work fine on my Droid Bionic and doesn't error out, but afterwards I can't find the image anywhere in the phone's storage. Where is it going? Is it possible to access images exported from an AIR app? Am I missing something completely obvious?

```
bdToSave.draw(screenshot);
var arrBytes:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bdToSave);
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("testimage.png");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();

try {
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeBytes(arrBytes);
    fileStream.close();
}
catch (errObject:Error) {
    Env.outBox.text = "Error writing image file!"
}
```

I've also used the CameraRoll class to successfully export images and found the resulting files easily, but the images there seemed to use bad JPEG compression. So I was hoping using FileStream instead would result in nicer images.

Comment: Are you getting a runtime error ? Does it fall to the try catch statement. You may have to add some extra permission to write on the SD card. Also, I remember somebody mentioning that disk writes made during a debugging session with AIR are not kept afterwards.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors that I can see. I've mostly been running it in device release mode. It doesn't hit the catch statement, and the code after the try/catch executes fine. I've enabled WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the permissions.

Comment: @AntoineLassauzay There is an option in the Debug Configurations to delete data on each launch, but it is not enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

`File.desktopDirectory` does not exist on Android. Use `File.applicationDirectory` or `File.applicationStorageDirectory` to write to the internal disk. You almost *always* want to use applicationStorageDirectory and I believe that is actually the *only* one you can use on iOS for writing data. For writing to external drives, and this is untested on my part, I believe you want to use `File.documentsDirectory`. Trace out `File.documentsDirectory.nativePath` to verify that is the correct path.

It might be wise to consider that the majority of higher-end phones being released now *do not* contain SD cards. If this is meant to be a mass market product, I'd recommend using applicationStorageDirectory instead.

Comment: I am saving other files in File.applicationStorageDirectory. However, I want users to be able to view and manipulate images exported from the game. While writing to File.applicationStorageDirectory is successful and I can access those files in Flash, I can't find them by going through the "Files" directory on the phone. Other apps create files and directories that are accessible through Files; where should I save things if I want my app to do the same?

Comment: Again, try `File.documentsDirectory` as I suggested in the answer. I've never tested it, but I have read that that maps out to the SD card on Android